# Mapping a user defined function with SSRS package parameters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, user-defined-functions

I have created the following User Defined Function :

```
CREATE FUNCTION MyTable
(
@dd_YearNo INT,
@txt_WeekNoFrom INT,
@txt_WeekNoTo INT,
@dd_Group VARCHAR(MAX),
@dd_Team VARCHAR(MAX),
@dd_SalesPerson NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS 
RETURN
SELECT *
FROM T1 (NOLOCK)
WHERE YearNo IN (@dd_YearNo)
AND (WeekNo BETWEEN @txt_WeekNoFrom AND @txt_WeekNoTo )
AND LEFT(Team,2) IN (@dd_Group)
AND Team IN (@dd_Team)
AND SalesPerson IN(@dd_SalesPerson)
```

I am using it as a my data set n SSRS like below :
[image]

How to map the parameters I created for my SSRS package to this user defined query. This is waht I get since I validate it :

[image]

These are the parameters I am using in my SSRS package and I am getting them from different queries :

[image]

I get the following error :

> Invalid Object MyTable

Comment: Instead of using the SP Parameters name you can use your SSRS report parameter.

Or else you can replace this TVF User function into an STORED PROCEDURE/ VIEW.

Comment: Aside: Your use of `in` with a `string` looks suspicious: `Team IN (@dd_Team)` and several others. Is there is a reason that you didn't simply use `Team = @dd_Team` or are you hoping that a comma-delimited list in `@dd_Team` will do what you _want_, not what you _wrote_?

Comment: **[Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)**

Comment: @HABO Team IN (@dd_Team) a member can be in different teams (a comma-delimited list in @dd_Team)

Comment: @SandraGuilepZouaouiZandeh That approach simply WILL NOT WORK - something you should know by now. To have your CSV string stored in a variable interpreted as a set of values requires either dynamic sql or a function to convert the string into a table of rows. The first step is to run your queries using SSMS to validate your code and logic using an adequate set of parameter values. If that isn't working, there is little point to using it as the basis for a report.

Comment: Unless there is a compelling reason to use a TVF then I would change your dataset to simply be the select statement from the function. The `IN` part of the statement will also be handled correctly by SSRS as long as the select statement is in the dataset query directly and not in an SP. You do NOT need to declare these variable in your statement doing it this way either. Much simpler.